# Disable control wrapping in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have a view that uses the following code.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab_1">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID, "Facility Name fwefwf wefwefwef wefwefe", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResidentID, "ResidentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResidentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResidentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, "Claim Amount", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

When the page is full screen the wrapping causes the controls to appear on the next line, instead of beside the label.

[WrappingControls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MZZZ.png)

How can I style the controls to have the textboxes appear on the same line as the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `<div class="form-group row">` to replace `<div class="form-group">`
Here is a demo:

```
<form>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab_1">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID, "Facility Name fwefwf wefwefwef wefwefe", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="Id">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResidentID, "ResidentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResidentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResidentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, "Claim Amount", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClaimAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

result:
[image]

If it is still not work,see the location of

[image]

in your layout and put it into `<footer></footer>`like this:

```
<footer>
            &copy;2020--Consultants For Long Time Care
</footer>
```